# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" Converting Google Sheet data into a Google Doc template using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-docs-api

Google sheet folder containing files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hPKQk7eRjSdlMDjiZI2BZrHIRhzVtYG5?usp=sharing

Im trying to fill out templates in google docs using data from my Test Merge google sheet file, specifically in the tab named "PrintThis". I have a Google Apps script added to my "Test Merge" google sheet file but im getting this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". The data in PrintThis will be varying in the number of rows so I am guessing the error is caused by this line?

```
    var tactics = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1xSWskGS8B_3Y35I4ycAjFZQiGbfJo13O3837RKnxnpk', 'A4:J');
```

But when I do A4:J6 just to test it for this static set of data it still gives me the same error. How do I fix this in a way that even when the PrintThis tab has a dynamic number of rows and my PrintThis tab can be moved(ex. a new sheet/tab can be placed on the left or right of the PrintThis tab)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the value of "Test Merge" using Sheets API, make sure to add the sheet name along with the range. Example: "Test Merge!A4:J"

**Example:**

[image: Test Data]

**Code:**

```
function myFunction() {

  Logger.log(Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('somespreadsheetid', 'Test Merge!A4:J').values);
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Test Data1]

Or

Since you are using Google Apps Script, you could use `SpreadsheetApp`.

**Code:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test Merge");
  var range = sh.getRange(4, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 4 + 1, 10);
  var val = range.getValues();
  Logger.log(val)
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

### References:

[SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

[Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! I added the sheet name as you suggested but it gives me a different error code when I run it: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined (line 25, file "Code")" Does that mean that the code is reading the first column of my sheet incorrectly?

Comment: To help us get better idea on what your error is, kindly include more code in your post above. Also, remove any confidential data to your code once you pasted it.

Comment: I think the fixed you mentioned solved the problem and I think Im having a different issue altogether so Ill create a new question for it. Thank you so much again!